# WebMethod in Asp.Net Prevent Script Injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xss, webmethod, antixsslibrary

Hi I have a WebMethod in asp.net and I call it from clientside ajax call.I use antixss library ,htmldecode and encode to prevent xss attack.But what I want can I do it globally.ValidateRequest prevent textbox from antixss in server side but they are not working in ajax call.